# Windows 11 Randomly Freezing Up

Tags: drivers, freeze, windows-11, integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen

Using an HP laptop running Windows 11 Home 64-bit. AMD Ryzen 5 5500U CPU with integrated Radeon Graphics. My drivers are working and up to date.

My PC has started freezing up randomly, sometimes not for the whole day, other times after a few minutes of use. All video suddenly stops, my wallpaper engine background freezes, scrolling becomes choppy, and buttons (UI, not keyboard) don’t work. What's weird is that it's not a complete lockup. I can still play my video games if they're running, although I can't load any other areas. I can switch tabs and scroll, although sometimes it gets stuck and I can't do anything anymore. It's weird and I haven't seen it documented well anywhere else. When I'm forced to turn it off manually and boot it up again, it starts around 80/90 degrees on Speccy.

It started around early march, with what I think is likely caused by a windows update, and I’ve been going insane trying to fix it. My drivers are up to date and cleaned by DDU. Reliability monitor and logs are no help. Sorry if this is poorly worded, I'm just stressed and annoyed.

Comment: Leave Task Manager running and turned to the Details tab, ordered perhaps  by CPU or I/O to see what is taking up resources. You can also use Process Monitor to record load: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Update BIOS and test.  Get HP's Hardware Diagnostic App and run that for hardware errors, especially disk.   .   If none, backup and reinstall Windows.  Make sure you do not install incompatible software.